# Simple whitespace check in AWK regex not working

Tags: regex, awk

I have a AWK script that goes through a file line by line and does various things with what it finds, which all work fine. Recently it was found that some lines need to be ignored, that all follow the format

```
        FOO_.....
```

So I need to match whitespace `FOO_`. There are also lines that I do not want to match that go

```
        BAR_...  FOO_...
```

So the match needs to be start of line. This should all be very easy and I set it up quickly

```
if($0 ~ /^\s*FOO_/)
{
    continue;
}
```

Unfortunately the above did not work. I tried a lot of checks until I finally was able to get this to work

```
if($0 ~ /^ *\t*FOO_/)
{
    continue;
}
```

So for some reason `\s*` does not correctly match the whitespace, but `*\t*` (one or more space, one or more tab) does work. The second one working means everything thats there to match is either a space or a tab, which should both be covered under `\s` so I'm really not sure why the `\s` won't work.

I can make it work with the other option, but its not ideal, and I'm just curious as to what could cause this issue.

Answer (score 6):

`\s` is a shorthand for the POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` that will only work in some awks. Sounds like the awk you're using isn't one of them.

Comment: I could have sworn we had other awk scripts that used the `\s`, but its possible I'm just thinking of different regex that isn't being done in awk. This could very well be the issue.

Comment: I recently bumped into this with the default awk and the solution was to install GNU awk (apt install gawk).

Comment: Agree with @Ed using it like: if($0 ~ /^[[:space:]]*FOO_/) can solve the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the default field separator, you can avoid this problem by checking if the *first word* starts with FOO_

```
if ($1 ~ /^FOO_/) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really sure why I didn't do it that way in the first place, other parts in the script use $0 because they check the first few words and I guess I just got caught up in doing things the same way without actually thinking about it.